# How to increase the length of the filter/sort menu in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I'm using the filter option to select through a list of "n" items in Excel.
The items are sorted in `ascending` order.
This is how the filter/sort (pop-up or context) menu appears when I click on it.
  [image: filter/sort menu-short].
I would like to have it longer as shown below.

[image: filter/sort menu-long]

I'm sure that there are no settings/options within Excel to make this change (because I've looked all over the place within Excel).  Where should I look in order to change this view?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the bottom right corner where the 3 dots are?

Comment: Yes. See the second image above. I came there by dragging as u said. It doesn't stay that way after u make a selection and visit it the next time